# Spark SQL Ranking for nullable unicode strings

Tags: apache-spark, unicode, null, apache-spark-sql, databricks

We are working on Spark SQL. We are doing ranking using some nullable string fields.

The problem is:  In Spark SQL, `null` values come first in the ranking. But, We want `null` value to come in the end. So, we have applied a CASE WHEN logic. As we are having Unicode data, "ZZZZZZZZ" will not be coming in the end. It will be ahead of Japanese, Chinese address lines.

Please let us know, which string constant literal to use for null string values, so that they come in the end in case of ORDER BY.

I have put sample code below.

```sql
SELECT CompanyName, 
ROW_NUMBER() OVER
                    (
                        PARTITION BY O.CompanyName
                        ORDER BY  
                                 CASE WHEN AddressLine1 IS NOT NULL THEN AddressLine1 ELSE "ZZZZZZZZ" END ASC                                 
                    ) AS BestDataForCompany
FROM CompanyData
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ranking functions in Spark SQL support the `NULLS LAST` argument so this will work:

```
SELECT 
  CompanyName,
  AddressLine1,
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY CompanyName ORDER BY AddressLine1 ) BestDataForCompany1,
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY CompanyName ORDER BY CASE WHEN AddressLine1 IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END, AddressLine1 DESC ) BestDataForCompany2,
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY CompanyName ORDER BY AddressLine1 NULLS LAST ) BestDataForCompany3  
FROM CompanyData
```

My results:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tested this - but I'm guessing you would be best partitioning them into another group then sorting that first. Then applying the real ranking you want:

```
SELECT CompanyName, 
ROW_NUMBER() OVER
                    (
                        PARTITION BY O.CompanyName, CASE WHEN AddressLine1 IS NOT NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
                        ORDER BY  
                                 CASE WHEN AddressLine1 IS NOT NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END, AddressLine1                                 
                    ) AS BestDataForCompany
FROM CompanyData
```

Comment: Hi Simon, SparkSQL does actually support `NULLS LAST` or `FIRST` with partition function so no need for a custom `CASE` expression.  Great huh?

Comment: Yup agreed. Nulls last is a better solution.